# Jpg with # in name not found

Tags: webserver, jpeg

I have an image on my web server called `image#01.jpg`.
If I go to `http://www.myserver.com/image#01.jpg` I receive a 404 error.

How I can solve?

Comment: rename your file and refrain from using special characters in file names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `#` has a special meaning in URLs you have to replace it with `%23`:

```
www.example.com/image%2301.jpg
```